# StyleBundle being rendered as ScriptBundle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My CSS `StyleBundle` is being rendered in a `<script>` tag instead of a `<link>` tag.

This has me scratching my head. I keep looking for my typo but everything looks fine.

This is my BundleConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));


    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
              "~/Content/themes/base/all.css"));

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
}
```

This is the head from my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
</head>
```

And this is how the HTML is rendered:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Content/themes/base/all.css"></script>


</head>
```

The layout is a bit off so something looks like it is up but I can't see what.  Why isn't it rendering the css file in a `<link>` tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your layout, this line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

Should be:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

Comment: Omg so obvious, I was going over this so many times and didn't see this. Thanks man